# How to create a keep-alive API endpoint with Cowboy in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, keep-alive, cowboy, plug

**Note:** I am new to elixir and the forum, and hence my question might be missing some details. Do let me know if additional information is required from my end.
I am trying to integrate the [trading view’s /streaming endpoint](https://www.tradingview.com/rest-api-spec/#operation/streaming).

**A snippet of what it says is:**
Stream of prices. **Server constantly keeps the connection alive**. **If the connection is broken - the server constantly tries to restore it**. **TradingView establishes up to 4 simultaneous connections to this endpoint and expects to get the same data to all of them**. Transfer mode is chunked encoding . The data feed should set 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' and make sure that all intermediate proxies are set to use this mode. All messages are to be ended with \n . Data stream should contain real-time data only. It shouldn’t contain snapshots of data.

Can anyone help me implement an endpoint that can keep the connection alive? I am using cowboy as the framework.

I have already used Plug’s send_response and send_chunked in conjunction with halt, but it did not work out.

Comment: Since you have to initiate the request, I think you need to use a HTTP client that supports async requests/streaming (like [httpoison](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison)).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.